# Does visual studio has compilation mode with multiple drop down boxes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, macros

I’m working with VisualStudio on a C++ project.
I have multiple solution configurations in my project. Each one has a different MACRO definition.

ConfigurationA: `define A`

ConfigurationB: `define B`

ConfigurationC: `define C`

Now I need a different orthogonal set of configurations with MACRO definition that can work with each one of the original Configurations.

ConfigurationX: `define X`

ConfigurationY: `define Y`

ConfigurationZ: `define Z`

I need the ability to compile in any permutation `{A, B, C} x {X, Y, Z}`.

Is there a way to avoid the definition of 9 solution configurations? (The real problem contains more than 3 configurations)
Is it possible for example to add another drop down menu in VisualStudio to select a second configuration?

Comment: Sounds to me you are trying to substitute a configuration file that you load at runtime with #defines.  Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has only one build configuration selector and there is no way to extend it using built-in functionality. However, maintaining nine build configurations (actually it will be more like 18 configs for each platform, since there should be Debug and Release versions as well) is pretty tedious process. To avoid it you could:

1. Use Windows environment variables to hold preprocessor defines and switch them using batch scripts or simple console program;
2. Use `msbuild` to build your app. Additional defines could be supplied at the command line which is easily scripted as well;
3. [Extend](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3A%22Configuration%20Manager%22&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance) Configuration manager using VS addin. Have not seen any even relatively close to what you want, but could simplify process nonetheless;
4. Create your own VS extension.